# What are the best drawing library for javascript?

Tags: javascript, canvas, svg, raphael, fabricjs

In my project we are trying to implement a UI that displays default configuration of the electrical switch panel with electrical components like Braker, Split Bus, Timer clock etc.

User can change the configuration manually by dragging and dropping the components or by adding new components to the default configurations.

I have googled alot to find any frame work or library that support these functionality but unable to find one.

Finally we decided to implement this by using anyone of the javascript drawing library and jquery drag and drop.

I have came across some of the interesting drawing libraray like `raphaeljs` `fabric.js` `Snap.svg` `paper.js`.Its very had to select which is good for the above use case.I will be very helpful if any one suggest a good library for the above use case Or guide me through which library will be best fix among the library mentioned above.Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Because of your specific needs to show connected components, I'd recommend you search for libraries that allow representation / manipulation of 'entity graphs' or 'network graphs' - of which there are many.

Look at the demos for each to see which ones give you better control over both the imagery as well as the connection types and methods that suit your application.

If you want a real shortcut to an 'MS Visio' like experience, and don't mind paying a commercial-use fee (assuming you intend to commercialise your project), then the [draw.io](https://www.draw.io/) team make their underlying [mxGraph](https://www.jgraph.com/) library available as a commercial license or under creative commons for non-commercial use, as well as [draw.io](https://github.com/vmassol/draw.io) itself under an Apache open source license.